# Mac Book Pro 2012 Terminal Pass Recovery

Tags: macbook-pro, terminal, password, keychain

Recently bought this computer and am not an administrator just trying to log previous owner out to log in via the use of the Terminal through accessing the physical written form of the password and using it to log prior owner out. Very basic understanding of coding and relatively new to the extensive study of it so details details details!

Answer (score 2):

This can be done by removing the .AppleSetupDone file, forcing the Mac to go back through the initial setup, part of which includes creating an admin account.  The following steps should walk you through that process:

1. Shutdown as normal
2. Power on your Mac while holding command+S to enter Single User mode
3. Type rm /var/db/.AppleSetupDone and press return
4. Type reboot and press return
5. The Mac should now reboot and go through the setup assistant, allowing you to create a new admin account.

Once you have an admin account you should be able to use sudo elevation in Terminal and remove any other user accounts on the system.

Comment: Worked like a charm my dude thank you kindly any info on terminal set up of a vpn also how to go about removing other users through terminal?

Comment: I'll advise to format and reinstall the Mac as you cannot with this method be sure that the system has not been tampered with. I.e. you cannot know for example if the system has been modified to record webcam video and send it to the previous owner.

Comment: @Alex - You're welcome!  Not sure how to set up VPN via terminal but there are built in GUI methods and third party options like Tunnelblick.  Check the man page for DSCL, that's typically how you add/modify/remove accounts via the command line.  Something like dscl . -delete "/Users/username" should work.  Search before trying that though.

Answer (score 1):

The best method of taking over a previously-owned Mac is to reinstall the operating system.

Power up your Mac while holding down the keys Command, Option and R.

Your Mac will boot up in Internet Recovery Mode allowing you to format the disk drive and installing macOS from scratch again.

After doing so you'll have a clean machine where you chose the logins and passwords.

Comment: Recovery or Internet recovery mode will not remove a user with administrative permissions.

Comment: If the macOS partition is formatted, it will remove the users, yes. However if there's a firmware password, it cannot be bypassed this way.

Comment: It's easiest to elevate his user account to administer computer and then remove admin permissions on the original account in order to remove the original administrative user. Then going about a recovery or reformatting.

Comment: I don' think that is a good solution, as you do not know what the previous owner "left behind" of malware or other things that might not be easily detected or overwritten when reinstalling macOS without formatting. If you're going to do a reformatting in the end, there's no point in removing the admin permissions of the original account.

Comment: The OP was addressing his concern in logging out an administrative user, not reformatting or reinstalling the operating system. There are very few malware for macOS, its not a relative issue.

Comment: I don't agree with that. If the previous owner had malicious intentions, he doesn't need to use actual "malware" software, but could use ordinary software for his purpose. As he was the administrator of the Mac he could install all sorts of monitoring software that the new owner wouldn't like to have. The best advice when buying a used computer is almost always to format and reinstall.